Cakewalk by band lab refuses to export sustain
I just recorded my MIDI keyboard with velocity and sustain into cakewalk. it seems to be recorded great, but when I export as MIDI, only the velocity works and there's no sustain effect. What am I doing wrong?



I think I need a VST but I dont know what to use and how to use it

With some googling I could find that sustain pedal sends CC64. Can you confirm that it's missing from the exported MIDI file? Your comment suggests it's an issue with playback of the MIDI file, not the contents?...

After you export the MIDI, what app are you using to open up the exported MIDI file?

From the first screenshot, looks like there are 2 controllers shown: Velocity and CC: 64-Pedal (sustain), but it's unclear if the value for CC 64 is shown (looks like Velocity is selected?). Could you edit and show that?
